# _setup:37 compstate: assignment to invalid subscript range

Tags: plugins, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Getting this error  `_setup:37: compstate: assignment to invalid subscript range`  when trying to navigate to a previously visited directory using zsh-z that has worked before.

**What is zsh-z?**

Zsh-z is a command line tool that allows you to jump quickly to directories that you have visited frequently in the past

The problem is fixed when I type this into my terminal `source ~/.zshrc` does anyone know a workaround where it all works without me typing anything into the terminal when I have restarted my computer? Anyone had this issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: You probably have only the chance to either report the error to the maintainers of the plugin, or to debug it by yourself. After all, you know the name of the file, where the error occurs, and the line number.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with an application called Fig that I had transferred from an old computer.

Fixed trough removing the app

Answer (score 4):

did you use an alias for "z" maybe?
if so, change it to:

```
unalias z 2> /dev/null
z() {
    [ $# -gt 0 ] && zshz "$*" && return
    cd "$(zshz -l 2>&1 | fzf --height 40% --nth 2.. --reverse --inline-info +s --tac --query "${*##-* }" | sed 's/^[0-9,.]* *//')"
}
```

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with an application called Fig that I had transferred from an old computer.

Fixed trough removing the app